# extract file name from content disposition

Tags: java, jersey

My payload has the Content-Disposition field. I am trying to upload a bpmn file. So at backend i need to parse the input stream and extract this file name. but i am not able to find a solution of this. I am using jesrey for rest.

I tried with :

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addWorkflowSchema(@FormDataParam("bpmndata") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
         String filename,
        @Context HttpServletRequest request)
```

to get whole payload data. but only if i remove FormDataParam i ma getting request body.

Reuqest Payload :

```
------WebKitFormBoundary8CCb878TyZksE9go
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="bpmndata"; filename="process.bpmn"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundary8CCb878TyZksE9go--
```

I need to get filename from Content-Disposition. How can i get this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just inject the [`FormDataContentDisposition`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.17/jersey/index.html?org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/FormDataContentDisposition.html) also, and get the file name from *that*.

```
public Response addWorkflowSchema(
                       @FormDataParam("bpmndata") InputStream in,
                       @FormDataParam("bpmndata") FormDataContentDisposition fdc) {

    String fileName = fdc.getFileName();
}
```

The `InputStream` will only be the content of the file part. It won't include the headers, so you don't need to extract anything from it.

Comment: For me doesn't work. 
No message body reader has been found for class com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition, ContentType: multipart/form-data
2018-06-21 14:21:33,016 http-nio-8080-exec-5 WARN - , - [o.a.c.j.i.WebApplicationExceptionMapper] - javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type

Comment: Yeah me neither

Comment: @CodeSlave you need to learn to ask good questions. By saying “yeah me neither,” what do expect to gain out of that? In you current post you say “it doesn’t work.” What doesn’t work? What is the exact problem? Have you posted enough information for someone to reproduce the exact problem? No one has time to go back and forth with you to ask questions about your problem. You should already post in as much detail as possible what the problem is and how can we reproduce it. Take time to read the help center in regards to asking good questions.

Comment: @CodeSlave I don’t mind answering questions, but when I feel like it will be more of a hassle to do so, I will tend to just pass on the question. I asked you read some posts? Did you? Did figure out how to register the MultiPartFeature? That was the point of you reading that.

Comment: Hi Paul. First of all thanks for your time. I read what you have posted to me and I manage to upload a file, but now I have the problem with boundaries. You are right, sorry I did not meant to be rude and I really mean that sorry. About this issue, I meant that I had the same problem as Stefano. I added FormDataContentDisposition but when Im testing from Postman I get: No message body reader has been found for class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition, ContentType: multipart/form-data
 javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type

Comment: @CodeSlave you will need to post another question with all the relevant info to reproduce the problem. This is not how SO is meant to work. It is a Q & A site not a help center. You ask a question and once it’s solve if you have another question then post another one. I cannot answer question without knowing more info

Comment: There could be many reasons for that error. Without more context I will only be guessing at the problem is.